# ows_MetaInfo field including carriage returns

Tags: 2010, infopath, reporting-services

I have an InfoPath 2010 form promoting fields to SP 2010.  Using SSRS 2008 R2, I'm pulling those fields into a report to report off of.  I'm finding that *some* fields in the ows_MetaInfo blob have a carriage return prefixed on them, in the format:

FieldName:SW|\nFieldValue

This is preventing the use of filters in SSRS as SSRS is seeing the "blank" line preceding the value as the value for the item.  How can I remove this carriage return on the InfoPath/SharePoint side, or deal with it on the SSRS side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this within the reports using the code:

```
Public Function StrStrp(str As String) As String
    str = str.TrimStart(Chr(10))
    Return str
End Function
```